# What files/folder do not belong on production?

Tags: security, deploy

Some community members suggest that folders like `downloader` and `dev` don't belong on a production environment.  Is there an official list somewhere?  What else has no place on the production server?

Answer (score 8):

> Is there an official list somewhere

Nope.

In general the folders we exclude from production are:

```
/dev
/downloader
.htaccess.sample
index.php.sample
install.php
LICENSE.html
LICENSE.txt
LICENSE_AFL.txt
LICENSE_EE.html
LICENSE_EE.txt
mage
php.ini.sample
RELEASE_NOTES.txt
```

There are exceptions here - for instance - if you don't include the LICENSE files you may not be able to install from scratch; so you'd definitely want to have it tracked in source control, but not deployed.

Obviously it will be hard to run the installer if `install.php` isn't in your source control either.

`/dev` and `/downloader` are the ones that I would advocate should never be in a production environment.

Comment: Note that if you plan on using Enterprise's staging feature, you need `.htaccess.sample` and `index.php.sample`.

Comment: Hahahahaa YES. But we refer to this as a "box ticker" ;)