# Attempted access to install.php

Tags: magento-1, installation, install-script

I sometime get Store Debug Information saying some attempted access to install.php.
Is is better to delete/rename install.php?

```
URL: http://mywebsite.com/install.php
IP Address: 
Time: 
Error:


Trace:
#0 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(861): Mage_Core_Model_App->throwStoreException()
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(502): Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore()
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(285): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore('default', 'store')
#3 /app/Mage.php(616): Mage_Core_Model_App->init('default', 'store', Array)
#4 /install.php(129): Mage::app('default')
#5 {main}
```

Comment: Yes, you can remove install.php from your production server.

Answer (score 0):

You can block install.php access by adding following line to .htaccess on magento's root directory

```
<Files install.php>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: Can be removed, see here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/82042/what-files-folder-do-not-belong-on-production

Comment: Yes you can remove, but why remove if we have option to make this unavailable for everyone. All magento files will remain same and there will be no issue while applying patch if any patch released for install.php

Comment: I see what you're talking about. Actually I am speaking of leaving the file in the development system but do not deploy it to production.